# How to get part of column in df in italics?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
number <- c(34,36,67,87,99)
mz <- c("m/z 565.45","m/z 577.45","m/z 65.49","m/z 394.22","m/z 732.43")  
df <- data.frame(number, mz)
```

However, I want the m/z part in italics, but I cannot figure out how to.

```
df$mz <- gsub('m/z', italic('m/z'), df$mz)
```

This does not work, I get the error:

```
Error in italic("m/z") : could not find function "italic"
```

This also does not work:

```
df$mz <- gsub('m/z', expression(italic('m/z')), df$mz)
```

I don't get an error but I get literally 'italic('m/z')' in my dataframe.
Is there any way around this?

EDIT:
The reason I want to do this is because I'm going to use the df to make a plot and I need the m/z to be in italics in the plot

Comment: It'll depend on how you're going to plot it. Please provide an example.

Comment: Do you want to evaluate in html parser.  Then `gsub('m/z', '<i>m/z</i>', df$mz)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store `mz` as character strings, then parse at the time of plotting:

```r
df$mz <- sub('m/z', 'italic(m/z)~', df$mz)
```

A base R plot would then look like this:

```r
plot(1:5, df$number, xaxt = 'n', xlab = 'mz')
axis(1, at = 1:5, labels = parse(text = df$mz))
```

[image]

And a ggplot like this:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(factor(1:5), number)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = parse(text = df$mz), name = 'mz')
```

[image]

Comment: Is it also possible to save it as *italic* elements in a dataframe?

Comment: @Quinten no, not really. Italic text is a mode of _printing normal glyphs_ rather than a value that is assigned to a glyph when it is stored. One can take normal ascii values and print them in italics. There are some high-value Unicode glyphs that represent italics, but they are not generally supported by most fonts.

Comment: When I try this solution, I get an error:
`Error in parse(text = df$mz) : <text>:1:13: unexpected numeric constant
1: italic(m/z) 565.45
                ^`

Comment: @Lieke sorry there was an error with the tilde character being copied across.  Can you try with the updated version?

Comment: It works! Thank so much. For my understanding, why do you need to add the tilde?

Comment: @Lieke it indicates an extra space - see `?plotmath`